# cause update panel in a user control to do partial page refresh from javascript / jquery

Tags: jquery, partial-page-refresh

I have a number of pages that each have 3 or 4 user controls on. each control has their own updatepanel in.

I am using JQuery and thickbox to create a modal window, where I open another aspx page and change some of the data.

What I want to do is to be able to refresh some or all of the update panels / content on the page when the modal window closes without refreshing the whole page.  I get a very annoying popup message sometimes within internet explorer when the modal window shuts, about refresh or cancel (do not have that text to hand at this moment).

I am pretty new to javascript and jquery and do not know which way to proceed with this.

Thank you

Jon Hawkins

Answer (score 2):

Within the onClose function or however you go about setting off the onClose event, you could do something like this so long as you have myObject defined as a trigger for the update panel.

```
function RefreshMyPanel() {
    var mypage = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    mypage._doPostBack('myObject', '');
}
```

I've not tested the code above, but it seems like this is one of the ways you can go about it.